# mpmovieplayercontroller load new audio url from background

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller

I have an MPMoviePLayerController that http streams audio files in succession from an xml playlist that is parsed into an array.

Issue is when a song is playing, and the phone gets locked, it keeps playing the song, background audio supported and all, till the end of the song....
but when calling:

```
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {...}
```

and I call the function to load the next track

```
- (void) LoadTrack:(int)indexToPlay {

    //use the generic APIContentObject.
    APIContentObject *currentTrack = [playlist objectAtIndex:indexToPlay];
    NSLog(@"%@",[currentTrack SluggedURL]);

    //get url
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[currentTrack FileURL]];

    //moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    if (!moviePlayer){

        moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    }else{

        //moviePlayer = nil;
        //moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

        //moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
        //[moviePlayer initWithContentURL:url];
        [moviePlayer setContentURL:url];        
        moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
        [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
        [moviePlayer play];
    }
    ...
```

It doesn't load the track and gives me the following in the output:

```
[MPCloudAssetDownloadController] Prioritization requested for media item ID: 0
```

as you can see by the commented lines I've tried a number of ways to solve this. None of which actually play the next song.
Is it because background audio needs to be a constant stream?
Can I not do it this way?

We have a CMS that users can change their playlists in, so it needs to be a mp3->-mp3 bridging while in background.

Plays current song fine, but why isn't it loading a new song?

or are network requests not considered part of 'background audio'?

Appreciate it much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realize that I cannot initiate any new URL conns while in the background. 
I need to switch to a m3u style playlist and use an on-demand media server to accomplish what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the UIBackgroundModes key in your info.plist file to "audio".
This will allow your app to still execute code while in the background.

Here's documentation just in case.
Link: [Check this link and scroll to: "Declaring Your App’s Supported Background Tasks"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)

I am having my own issue with mpmovieplayercontroller and while searching for help I found your post.

I am currently playing audio with mpmovieplayercontroller, when the song ends (moviePlayBackDidFinish), I ask the server for the next song url. And then that song plays.. rinse and repeat. It works fine when the screen is locked (meaning it *is* initiating a url connection when the app is in background and the screen is locked).